# HLA password program with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: dynamic, passwords, hla

This HLA program is to ask the user for a certain number of passwords, let the user enter them in twice for verification (MISMATCH is no match). Everything works fine, but if I would enter in two passwords, such as qwerty and foo, it would only print out:

```
Verification:
foo
foo
```

I can't rack my brain around this logic, because the dword pass1 should allow all of the different passwords to be printed out, any thoughts?

```
#include ("stdlib.hhf");
static
strname: string;
strname2: string;
mismatch: string := "MISMATCH";
num: int32 := 0;
pass1: dword;

procedure Password;
begin Password;
    if( str.eq(strname, strname2)) then
    stdout.put("Passwords match!!!", nl, nl);
    mov(strname,[ecx+ebx]);
    else
    stdout.put("NO MATCH!!!", nl, nl);
    mov(mismatch,[ecx+ebx]);
    endif;
end Password;

begin week3;
xor (eax,eax);
stdout.put("How many passwords are you entering? ", nl);
stdin.geti32();
mov(eax,num);

shl(2,num);
mem.alloc(num);
mov(eax,pass1);

stralloc(64);
mov(eax,strname);
stralloc(64);
mov(eax,strname2);

mov(pass1,ecx);
for(mov(0,ebx);ebx<num;add(4,ebx)) do
    stdout.put("Enter password (64 CHARACTERS MAX): ", nl);
    stdin.flushInput();
    stdin.gets(strname);
    mov(eax,[ecx+ebx]);
    stdout.put("Enter again: ", nl);
    stdin.flushInput();
    stdin.gets(strname2);
    mov(eax,[ecx+ebx]);
    Password();
    endfor;

stdout.put("Verification: ", nl);
for(mov(0,ebx);ebx<num;add(4,ebx)) do
    stdout.put((type string [ecx+ebx]), nl);
    endfor;

strfree(strname);
strfree(strname2);
mem.free(pass1);
end week3;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: okay. thanks i will.

Answer (score 0):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- HLA (High Level Assembler - HLABE back end, POLINK linker)
  Version 2.16 build 4413 (prototype)
- Windows 10

***NOTE***

- The primary issue is in the password procedure the same location in memory, strname, is always added to the pass1 variable.

```
if( str.eq(strname, strname2)) then
    stdout.put("Passwords match!!!", nl, nl);
    mov(strname,[ecx+ebx]);
else
```

- The code prints the same password during verification because the code saved the same location and that location contains just one string. The password printed will always be the last string stored at that location.
- The example below corrects this issue by allocating another 64 bit string, copying the verified password to it, and saving that new location in the memory allocated for passwords.

***EXAMPLE***

- ***WARNING: NOT SUITABLE FOR DEPLOYED PASSWORD MANAGEMENT***

```
program main;
#include ("stdlib.hhf");

static
    Original:   string;
    Matching:   string;
    MisMatch:   string := "MISMATCH";
    NumberOfPasswords: int32 := 0;
    PasswordLocations: dword;

begin main;
    stdout.put("How many passwords are you entering? ", nl);
    stdin.get(NumberOfPasswords);
    mov(NumberOfPasswords, EDX);

    shl(2, EDX);
    mem.alloc(EDX);
    mov(EAX, PasswordLocations);
    mov(EAX, ECX);

    stralloc(64);
    mov(EAX, Original);
    stralloc(64);
    mov(EAX, Matching);

    for(mov(0, ESI); ESI < NumberOfPasswords; inc(ESI)) do
        stdout.put("Enter password (64 CHARACTERS MAX): ", nl);
        stdin.flushInput();
        stdin.gets(Original);

        stdout.put("Enter again: ", nl);
        stdin.flushInput();
        stdin.gets(Matching);

        if( str.eq(Original, Matching)) then
            stdout.put("Passwords match!!!", nl, nl);
            stralloc(64);
            str.cpy(Original, EAX);
            mov(EAX, [ECX + ESI*4]);
        else
            stdout.put("NO MATCH!!!", nl, nl);
            mov(MisMatch, [ECX + ESI*4]);
        endif;
    endfor;

    stdout.put("Verification: ", nl);
    for(mov(0, ESI); ESI < NumberOfPasswords; inc(ESI)) do
        stdout.put((type string [ECX + ESI * 4]), nl);
    endfor;

    strfree(Original);
    strfree(Matching);
    mem.free(PasswordLocations);

end main;
```